# magento bassi-banner slider transition effect

Tags: slider, magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7.0.2. I installed the slide banner extension "bassi banner slider" and configured it to display 2 images with slide transition effect. The images are displayed but during the transition effect, both images are visible (one under the other) in front of the rest of the page. Does anyone know how to overcome this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted the creator of the extension. The problem occurred because the size of the images was not the same.